# PHP - preg_match confusion - not checking for correct character set - needs spaces

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm currently building an application that will have addresses inside it and I'm using preg_match to do some character detection and throw an error the user's way if they use invalid characters to make sure it's secure.

My problem is using preg_match it seems to be behaving strangely and I don't think I'm using it correctly or not because of how it's acting.

My code below should allow letters A to Z, both upper and lowercase for the City, County and Country. The code below is an example of the city when that field is updated:

```
// The user wants to update the city so let's go through the update process
if ( isset($_POST['city']) ) {

    // Check that the city is different before we try to update it
    if ( $newcompanycity != $companycity ) {

        // Check that the city is less than 50 characters and contains valid characters
        if ( (strlen($newcompanycity) <= 50) && (preg_match('/[^A-Za-z]/', $newcompanycity)) ) {

            // The city is fine so let's update it
            $update_success = true;
            mysqli_query($sql, "UPDATE clients SET city = '$newcompanycity' WHERE companyid = '$companyid'") or die(mysqli_error($sql));

        } else {

            // The city doesn't meet the requirements to be update so return an error
            $update_fail = true;
            $city_error = true;

        }

    }

}
```

Now the issue is that `$city_error` is being triggered when the current value is "Sheffield" and you change it to "York" it returns an error as the `$city_error` variable becomes true. However changing the value from "Sheffield" to "Sheffield 1", it then works and updates the database.

Am I missing something here? I thought that A-Za-z only checks for letters and if there are only letters then it should work. But this doesn't seem to be working at all.

---

Just a quick update before I posted this. I just realised I need to add a space at the end of string and then it works. I'm really confused with this. So without a space it returns an error as preg_match doesn't allow it but with a space even though it's not defined inside preg_match it allows it. Surely this isn't normal behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is `/[^A-Za-z]/` which means something like "everything that is not A-Z and a-z".
The [preg_match](http://php.net/preg_match) function returns the number of matches, so if no invalid characters were found it should return 0.

So if you change `(preg_match('/[^A-Za-z]/', $newcompanycity))` to `(preg_match('/[^A-Za-z]/', $newcompanycity) === 0)` it should work as expected as it becomes true if no invalid characters where found.

To include whitespaces just add them to your regex: `/[^A-Za-z ]/`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, using the three equal signs fixed it. I was battling this for ages so thanks, finally working!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes regexp only further complicates things. PHP has a great function called `ctype_alpha()` that will check if a variable is only A-Za-z.

```
(ctype_alpha($newcompanycity))
```

Here's a [working example for you](https://eval.in/376859)

Comment: Thanks for that! I had no idea that existed, so useful. I'll use that instead. Does that allow spaces (whitespace) at all or would that return an error if whitespace was used?